# Can't find my app's full home page in Android Studio Layout Editor

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-layout, mobile

Prerequisites: Got a working app from a friend who needs some changes made. They were outsourcing and now want to internally manage it.
I come from a web and game dev background, so Android/IOS development is new to me, but a lot of the principles seem to be the same.
I got the project onto my device, installed all of the dependencies, and fixed all of the file paths.
The app successfully builds, and I have my virtual Android device running it great!

However, my buddy wants some really simple layout changes, and for the life of me, I can't find where to just edit the home screen layout. I was trying to solve my issue from a web dev approach, by grepping where the logo screen is used in the app, but those files seem to just load a white "background" layer, and not the entire composed page?

I'm missing something really silly here, and I just want to ask a real person on here, instead of digging through documentation and trying to word a condensed question in a Google search.

Here are my condensed questions: How can I just edit the home screen of my app in Android Studio? Where can I find the full home page file to view the entire layout, and not just a fragment?

Edit: The app also utilizes the Flutter SDK, which may explain why I have been having trouble with layout edits. I'm going to look at it again after work today, and hopefully answer my own question. I appreciate the help so far!

Edit 2: After going back to the app with a different approach, I found out my project had defaulted to the "android" sub folder of my master, and wasn't showing any of the Flutter .dart documents. After going up one folder directory, I was finally able to access that Main.Dart file with the display information.
I was able to mount it for inspection, but its saying my emulated device isn't supported. I need to look at it when I have time tonight, and may need to ask a separate question for it. I have my project sdk set to Android 33, and my virtual device is set to Android version 33. I searched around Stack, with a few people with reporting similar issues. I tried following their solutions, but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: What the app is made with? Flutter or Android? Because you don't modify the layout the same way on Android or Flutter.

Comment: If you're using Flutter, start with `main.dart`. From there, you'll be able to find the entrypoint of your app.

Comment: Ahhh, okay it is Flutter! That may explain a lot of the trouble I've been having, because I was mainly looking at the Android Studio docs, not Flutter.
Let me come back to this question later, and hopefully either edit it or answer it. I appreciate the help! I know it seems silly, but this nudge is just what I needed to set me on the right path.